# Exclude some tests by default

Tags: python, pytest

I wish to configure `pytest` such that it excludes some tests by default; but it should be easy to include them again with some command line option. I only found `-k`, and I have the impression that that allows complex specifications, but am not sure how to go about my specific need...

The exclusion should be part of the source or a config file (it's permanent - think about very long-running tests which should only be included as conscious choice, certainly never in a build pipeline...).

Bonus question: if that is not possible, how would I use `-k` to exclude specific tests? Again, I saw hints in the documentation about a way to use `not` as a keyword, but that doesn't seem to work for me. I.e., `-k "not longrunning"` gives an error about not being able to find a file "notrunning", but does not exclude anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pytest to mark some tests and use -k arg to skip or include them.

For example consider following tests,

```
import pytest

def test_a():
    assert True

@pytest.mark.never_run
def test_b():
    assert True


def test_c():
    assert True
    
@pytest.mark.never_run
def test_d():
    assert True
```

you can run pytest like this to run all the tests

```
pytest
```

To skip the marked tests you can run pytest like this,

```
pytest -m "not never_run"
```

If you want to run the marked tests alone,

```
pytest -m "never_run"
```

Answer (score 3):

goal: by default skip tests marked as `@pytest.mark.integration`

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest

# function executed right after test items collected but before test run
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    if not config.getoption('-m'):
        skip_me = pytest.mark.skip(reason="use `-m integration` to run this test")
        for item in items:
            if "integration" in item.keywords:
                item.add_marker(skip_me)
```

**pytest.ini**

```
[pytest]
markers =
    integration: integration test that requires environment
```

now all tests marked as `@pytest.mark.integration` are skipped unless you use

```
pytest -m integration
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past is create custom markers for these tests that way I can exclude them using the `-m` command line flag for running the tests. So for example in your `pytest.ini` file place the following content:

```
[pytest]
markers =
    longrunning: marks a test as longrunning
```

Then we just have to mark our long running tests with this marker.

```
@pytest.mark.longrunning
def test_my_long_test():
    time.sleep(100000)
```

Then when we run the tests we would do `pytest -m "not longrunning" tests/` to exclude them and `pytest tests` to run everything as intended.